# Numeric if conditions that read a command in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic

I'm trying to write a command that looks at my battery state and suspends the laptop if the battery is low. I tried using something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(acpi -b | cut -c 25) < 11 ]
then notify-send "Hello"
fi
```

This works, but for some reason if I replace 11 with a one-digit number like 5, I get an error

```
battery-notify-standby: line 2: 5: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to replace the square bracket with two round brackets to designate it as an arithmetic expression. Then I get

```
battery-notify-standby: line 2: ((: < 11 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< 11 ")
```

I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong. Can someone help me out?

Comment: what does `printf '-%s-' $(acpi -b | cut -c 25)` display?

Comment: `cut -c 25` will output at most one character, so if it's a digit, it's going to always represent a number smaller than 11. And, well, you're not showing what the output of `acpi -b` is, but if it happens to contain the battery charge status as a percentage, it's likely that it'd usually require two digits to represent. That is orthogonal to how `<` works within `[ ]` or how to do a numeric comparison in the shell, but you may wish to reconsider if that `cut -c 25` is correct anyway, since any issues there may cause further issues with the numeric comparison too.

Comment: @ilkkachu My idea was that it should return the first digit of the percentage if the laptop is on battery, which is the 25th digit. I used 11 just to test whether it worked at all. You're right though that the method causes some problems, since the first digit is 1 if the laptop is at 100%.

Comment: Show the output of `acpi -b` so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `<` operator in shells is redirection, not a comparison operator. You seem to have a file called `11`, so that seems to get read, and that works. (but has nothing to do with checking the output – always verify your hypotheses!)

The comparison operator you're looking for is `-lt`, not `<`.

Comment: This should have worked when the op changed the test to `(( ))` if his command resulted in a valid number.

Comment: Marcus, the `<` and `>` operators are valid inside `(( … ))` expression evaluation (but not inside `[ … ]`)

Comment: Agreed, that's why I specifically said they need to check their presumptions!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your command `$(acpi -b | cut -c 25)` is in error.  When you changed the `[ ]` to `(( ))` the error is the same as if your command produced a blank

```
bash -c '((  < 11))'
bash: line 1: ((: < 11: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< 11")
```